# The existence of Meeseeks

Tags: rick-and-morty

In the first season (***Season 01 Episode 05: Meeseeks and Destroy***), Rick gives the Smith family a Meeseeks box to get them off his backs. From the actual script:

> **Rick**: *As for you dingdongs This is a Meeseeks box.*
>
> *Let me show you how it works.*
>
> *You press this.*
>
> **Meeseek**: *I'm Mr.Meeseeks! Look at me!*
>
> **Rick**: *You make a request. Mr. Meeseeks, open Jerry's stupid mayonnaise jar.*
>
> **Meeseek**: *Yes, siree!*
>
> **Rick**: *The Meeseeks fulfills the request.And then it stops existing*.

Later we find out that the Meeseeks cannot die until the requests are fulfilled. But when Jerry's requests go out of hand and a bunch of Meeseeks fail to fulfill his two-stroke request, they all decide to kill him.

Although, it all ends well for both the Smiths and the Meeseeks, had they been successful in killing Jerry, would it be suffice for the to *no longer exist* and go back to *not-existing anymore*?

Comment: This question seems purely opinion based and speculative, given no information is given. Any _on-topic_ answer would be a simple "We don't know, as far as we know there task wouldn't be complete"

Comment: @Edlothiad I too thought it might seem opinion based. but seeing that the meeseeks decided to kill him, i wondered if the creators of the show gave some explanation about it. OR maybe the meeseeks were simply dumb enough not to realize that they would be stuck?

Comment: As far as I can find, no. Although I haven't searched all too hard

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It would appear top me that the Meeseeks strategy is quite sound, it would seem that for the specific request Jerry made killing him would suffice (at least the Meeseeks think so). As for if this would work for everyone and every request, I'm not sure.

> Meeseek *: The job can't be done! We'll never get two strokes off his game!
>   Meeseek: No, we won't. **But we will get all strokes off his game.**
>   All other Meeseeks: Where's he going with this? What's he mean?
>   Meeseek: **When we kill him!**
>   <sub>Rick and Morty, Season 1 Episode 5, "Meeseeks and Destroy"</sub>

To be honest their logic seems quite reasonable they're getting all the strokes off his game thus "bettering it".

On a related note the Meeseeks seems to disappear depending on their own satisfaction with the task completion so it would appear as though killing Jerry would suffice, at least for most of them as Stickler Meeseeks wants more and would probably assume killing him to be a loophole.

> Meeseeks: Excuse me. I'm a bit of a stickler Meeseeks. What about your short game?
>   Samantha: Oh, my God, oh, my God! What about your short game?!
>   Meeseek: Ooh, nice! (Stops existing)
>   <sub>ibid</sub>

Comment: Like I said, opinion based speculation, although reasonably good speculation, that's all it will be unfortunately.

Comment: @Edlothiad To me the part about the stickler Meeseeks is all we need. It would appear it is a subjective thing for each Meeseeks on the completion of the task. If they think by killing Jerry their task is complete I'm pretty sure they'd stop existing.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot I agree, Stickler Meeseeks definitely seems to suggest it's the Meeseek's own opinion that determines whether he'd cease to exist, and if they all agreed to that course of action, they must have believed it would work.

Comment: So in short, the meeseeks are really helpful but kinda stupid at the same time. :p